# nginx route all requests to a pre-backend service before sending to upstream

Tags: nginx, routing

I need to route every request to 2 upstreams one after another (1st `auth-server`, 2nd `misc-server`). 1st upstream may or may not add headers and may/ may not alter request body.

> Upstreams API can be POST/GET

Can we do something like below with nginx:

```
    upstream auth-server {
        server localhost:8800 weight=5;
    }
    upstream misc-server {
        server localhost:8800 weight=5;
    }

    server {    
    location /misc {
        proxy_pass http://auth-server/misc/auth/pre; #1st route to this
    }
    location /misc {
        proxy_pass http://misc-server/misc; #2nd route to this
    }

}
```

The reason I'm trying to achieve this is for request validation by 1st upstream ie `auth-server` before actually routing request to destination upstream ie `misc-server`. Is this advisable?

Comment: This is a terrible application design. It should not be done at all in a production app. The app server cannot be sure that the user is authenticated or authorized, because it was bypassed. That said, you can probably pull some dirty trick with the third-party lua module.

Comment: @MichaelHampton all I want is to decouple authorization logic from multiple microservices so I decided to create a upstream and have it PRE-PROCESS all requests. In case, this auth upsteam fails to validate a request, it wont be send to misc-upstream by nginx.  Still terrible?

Comment: Yes, it's terrible. It is not nginx that needs to authenticate and authorize the user, but your other microservices. Those other microservices, not nginx, should be talking to your auth microservice. It is not possible to simply trust the external environment has authenticated the user correctly. What if someone bypassed nginx and was able to talk to your microservice directly? They could fake authentication and do anything.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how about I put one nginx in DMZ and one nginx in prod and have nginx do autorization via lua?

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: Only valid approach here is that your microservices to verify authentication status from your authentication microservice. nginx is meant for serving static files and passing requests to application services. nginx is not meant for complex application features like authentication.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen But I prefer not to make every microservice call auth-service before serving request. I'd want a gateway to pre-call auth-service before submitting it to a microservice. What's the standard here?

Comment: It was already explained by Michael above that your plan makes the system less secure.